# How to update only one field using Views?

Tags: views

Is it possible to update only one field using Views? Say, you use Views to list all property items. Property content type has one field called 'Position' with option values as 'Featured', 'Hot', 'Sold', 'Vacant', etc.. For each item in a row listed you have what looks like the following:

Views Display:

```
ID   Title     Type       Address       Total Size (sq Ft)     Position        Action
123  Bay View  Apartment  Moroco        1245                   (combobox)      Update
```

There are other fields for this content type that will not be included, hence, only those relevant fields are shown in this particular Views. So when you click 'Update' button the item will be updated accordingly, that is, only the 'Position' will be updated.

And maybe for other instances, a few fields - instead of one as above - can also be updated. The above is only an example with one field.

Any ideas?

Comment: try Editable Fields module, but I'm not sure you can allow only 1 field of the view to be editable offhand. The module page is at: https://www.drupal.org/project/editablefields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try the module [Editable fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/editablefields) It is an old module that hasn't been updated in a long time, but I did get it working recently on a new project.

Another option is to build your own with [rules, and rules links](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_link)

With rules links you can set a path that sets a rule to activate. You can have that rule update the content with whatever setting you wish.